# Modulate contrast gradient with a sine wave to generate a sine grating

Tags: ios, ipad, graphics, drawing

I need to generate an image output on an iPad similar to this (from Wikipedia):

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SinVibr.png

I've done similar gratings in MATLAB, using vectors with a sine wave on the x-axis and decreasing its amplitude on y-axis (for each row)

I'm doing it in iOS for usability reasons.

Re-implementing it on iOS using a simple loop and then presenting it as an image would work.

However it seems quite inelegant, since I wouldn't use any drawing APIs other than to present the image. Especially since I might need to rapidly update the image (at least 30 fps or more in a possible future version)

I've looked at CoreGraphics but for me it's non-obvious how to implement it. 
Should I look into OpenGL? Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking how to generate the image, or how to display it using ios. Have you considered generating the image in a pixel shader? If you need it to be rapidly updated, that might be the best option.